# Building sequential urls with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a text file that has 1 number in it.  i'm trying to have it go to the website with the first number appended to the url, grab the info and then move on to the next url in sequence, pull the info etc.  If the number brings up a blank page, it should end the sequence and email out the information it gathered.  I'm not getting any errors.  It completes it's run, but i'm not getting any back or seeing any changes in the number in the text file.  I'm curious if what i've got for this part of the program is correct, or if i'm missing something.

[Here's what I've got](http://www.wvlabor.com/new_searches/contractor_RESULTS.cfm?wvnumber=WV%7B%7D&contractor_name=&dba=&city_name=&County=&Submit3=Search+Contractors')

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


#loads LIC# url
def get_page(license_number):
    url = URL_FORMAT.format(license_number)
    r = requests.get(url)
    return bs(r.text, 'lxml')

#looks for non-existent info for no-license
def license_exists(soup):
    if soup.find('td', class_ = 'style3'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

#pulls lic# from text license_number.txt
def get_current_license_number():
    with open(LICENSE_NUMBER_FILE, 'r') as f:
        return int(f.read())

#adds lic# to urls
def get_new_license_pages(curr_license_num):
    new_pages = []
    more = True
    curr_license_num +=1

    return new_pages
```

Comment: The name `curr_license_num` is local to `get_new_license_pages`, so doing `curr_license_num +=1` has no effect outside that function. But what's that function supposed to do? It creates an empty list & does nothing with it, sets a local name `more` to True, and does nothing with that, either.

Comment: ok, i'm totally confused by functions.  Can't seem to wrap my head around it. The get_new_license_pages is supposed to take the current license number and replace it with the next sequential number in the url (i've added the url to the code above).  the more, well, i have no idea.  I am working through examples i've found online to put this all together.  I apologize if this is rudimentary question.  I do appreciate the help.